# Cannot resolve android annotation for sharedPreferences

Tags: android-studio, android-annotations

I imported this project from eclipse. everything is sorted out but there is this one issue I'm stuck with.

I've a sharedPreference interface which is done using annotations

```
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.DefaultBoolean;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.DefaultString;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.SharedPref;

@SharedPref
public interface RememberMePrefs {

@DefaultString("")
String email();

@DefaultString("")
String password();

@DefaultBoolean(true)
boolean enabled();
}
```

when I try to use this interface like this :

```
@Pref
RememberMePrefs_ rememberMePrefs;
```

it says "Cannot resolve symbol RememberMePrefs_"

this is my Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
def AAVersion = '4.6.0'
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
implementation files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
implementation files('libs/androidannotations-api-2.7.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/saripaar-11242012.jar')
implementation files('libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
implementation files('libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
implementation files('libs/actionbarsherlock.jar')
}
```

Any help will be appriciated as I've never worked on annotations before.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the latest AndroidAnnotations library in your build.gradle, but importing the old namespace in your Java code.

You should import:

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.DefaultBoolean;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.DefaultString;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.SharedPref;
```

This should be done in other classes as well, probably.